# The Mississipi counting problem, this time in circle

Tags: combinatorics

I have another version of the Mississippi problem.
How many ways we can arrange the letters, if we put them in a circle:
**Mississippi** and **Ississippim** - are the same.
I can't find a practical way to solve it. any suggestions?

Comment: Are clock wise and anti clock wise direction consider as a same?

Comment: This seems like an application of Polya's enumeration theorem, *n'est-ce pa*?

Answer (score 3):

**M** is an only unique element. So, seat **M** first.
This breaks the symmetry of a round table, and remaining seats just act as a straight line.

So, you have to seat $$i,i,i,i,s,s,s,s,p,p$$ i.e. 10 elements in a row. Do this in: $$\frac{10!}{4!\cdot4!\cdot2!}$$
This is the total number of arrangements.